# Updating parent model and all children

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am creating a simple WebApi for Recipes. A recipe contains both ingredients and instructions. I think I got most of the WebApi down, except for the Update() part.

I am not quite sure if I am doing it the right way. My code looks very long and complicated.

Is there an easier way to update parent and all children?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] RecipeViewModel recipeViewModel)
{
    var recipeToUpdate = _unitOfWork.RecipeRepository.Get(filter: r => r.RecipeId == id,
    includeProperties: "Ingredients,Instructions").FirstOrDefault();

    recipeToUpdate.Name = recipeViewModel.Name;
    recipeToUpdate.Description = recipeViewModel.Description;
    recipeToUpdate.Image = recipeViewModel.Image;

    foreach (var oldIngredient in recipeToUpdate.Ingredients)
    {
        var newIngredient = recipeViewModel.Ingredients.Where(ingredient => ingredient.IngredientId == oldIngredient.IngredientId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (newIngredient == null)
        {
            recipeToUpdate.Ingredients.Remove(oldIngredient);
            _unitOfWork.IngredientRepository.Delete(oldIngredient);
        }
        else
        {
            oldIngredient.Value = newIngredient.Value;
            oldIngredient.Name = newIngredient.Name;
            oldIngredient.Position = newIngredient.Position;
            oldIngredient.Unit = newIngredient.Unit;
            _unitOfWork.IngredientRepository.Update(newIngredient);
        }
    }
    foreach (var newIngredient in recipeViewModel.Ingredients)
    {
        var oldIngredient = recipeToUpdate.Ingredients.Where(ingredient => ingredient.IngredientId == newIngredient.IngredientId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (oldIngredient == null)
        {
            recipeToUpdate.Ingredients.Add(newIngredient);
            _unitOfWork.IngredientRepository.Insert(newIngredient);
        }
        else
        {
            oldIngredient.Value = newIngredient.Value;
            oldIngredient.Name = newIngredient.Name;
            oldIngredient.Position = newIngredient.Position;
            oldIngredient.Unit = newIngredient.Unit;
            _unitOfWork.IngredientRepository.Update(oldIngredient);
        }
    }
    
    foreach (var oldInstruction in recipeToUpdate.Instructions)
    {
        var newInstruction = recipeViewModel.Instructions.Where(instruction => instruction.InstructionId == oldInstruction.InstructionId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (newInstruction == null)
        {
            recipeToUpdate.Instructions.Remove(oldInstruction);
            _unitOfWork.InstructionRepository.Delete(oldInstruction);
        }
        else
        {
            oldInstruction.Position = newInstruction.Position;
            oldInstruction.Description = newInstruction.Description;
            _unitOfWork.InstructionRepository.Update(oldInstruction);
        }
    }
    foreach (var newInstruction in recipeViewModel.Instructions)
    {
        var oldInstruction = recipeToUpdate.Instructions.Where(instruction => instruction.InstructionId == newInstruction.InstructionId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (oldInstruction == null)
        {
            recipeToUpdate.Instructions.Add(newInstruction);
            _unitOfWork.InstructionRepository.Insert(newInstruction);
        }
        else
        {
            oldInstruction.Position = newInstruction.Position;
            oldInstruction.Description = newInstruction.Description;
            _unitOfWork.InstructionRepository.Update(oldInstruction);
        }
    }

    _unitOfWork.RecipeRepository.Update(recipeToUpdate);

    await _unitOfWork.Save()
}
```

And these are my models and my view model:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IdentityUser? Creator { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A recipe must have a name"), MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A recipe must have a description"), MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient>? Ingredients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Instruction>? Instructions { get; set; }
    public string? Image { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An ingredient must have a value")]
    public Decimal? Value { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An ingredient must have a unit")]
    public string? Unit { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An ingredient must have a name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Instruction
{
    public int InstructionId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An instruction cannot be empty")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class RecipeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A recipe must have a name"), MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A recipe must have a description"), MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ingredient>? Ingredients { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Instruction>? Instructions { get; set; }
    public string? Image { get; set; }
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: With EF you do not have to call Update at all, changes in objects are detected automatically. `Update` is attaching method. Try do not introduce anti-patterns like Repository. KISS.

Comment: Was the problem resolved? Is there anything else do you need any further assistance?